# Go to line in vs code, but with offset instead of exact line number

Tags: visual-studio-code

Long story short, I get call stacks, and they indicate a line number, but that number is an offset within the method. So i get line 40, but because the procedure starts at 120, it's really 160.

What I would love is to be able to enter that offset in the go to line function (ctrl+g). I don't know if there is a way to do it and I am just completely missing it / google failing me, or if it's something I'd have to write my own extension for.

Thanks.

Comment: but where do you set the procedure start line, for you it is a procedure for some others it is some special comment

Comment: What? This isn't relevant to the question. I'm on line 123. I want to move up 56 lines without doing maths. That's it. That's the question.

Comment: your question is that you want to go to a line that is offset (40) to some beginning (procedure start, 120), not relative to the current line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by#move-by) v1.18.0 you can construct a **Relative Goto Line** command

Add the following key binding:

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+alt+g",  // or any other key binding
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "moveby.calculation",
    "args": {
      "lineNrEx": "selection.start.line+relative",
      "charNrEx": "selection.start.character"
    }
  }
```